# What's the difference between slider and seekbar in android

Tags: android, xml, material-design, android-seekbar, android-slider

I am new to Android and i am learning SeekBars. in [Google material design site](https://material.io/components/sliders) i found Sliders from (com.google.android.material.slider.Slider) package instead of seekbars. I wonder what the difference is between Slider and SeekBar, which should I use and which is better? What is the purpose of implementing these two? I search a lot and There is no useful content on the internet

Comment: If you look for an answer on which you should use/is better; you might begin with telling a bit more about what your are trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: @Daan That's exactly my question. What is the purpose of these two?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*The following may not be entirely accurate to the last detail, but it illustrates some of the history well enough:*

`Slider` is just the MDC version of `SeekBar` - named a little differently and with a lot more functionality.

First, there was only `SeekBar` - the original framework UI component bundled with Android.
Then, `AndroidX` libraries, previously called `Support Libraries`, were created for backporting new UI components and bugfixes to older phones which OEMs refused to update anymore. The `AndroidX AppCompat` subproject swaps out all your framework components for the "fixed" versions whenever you use `AppCompatActivity`. `SeekBar` -> `AppCompatSeekBar`, `TextView` -> `AppCompatTextView`...
[image: SeekBar and AppCompatSeekBar illustration]

The old `Support Libraries` also had a package named `design` which contained some of the then-new `Material 1.0` components (`CardView` and whatnot) which didn't have a framework counterpart. That's the reason why there is no `AppCompatCardView` - because there is no framework `CardView`, so there is nothing to "fix" with AppCompat.

If I recall correctly, the `design` package of the `Support Libraries` later became the starting point for the Android implementation of `Material Components` when `Material 2.0` was unveiled. Material Design has its own version of `SeekBar` which is called `Slider` and it can do everything the old Android `SeekBar` can plus a lot more.
[image: Material Slider XML illustration]

**As for which one to use?** (Neither is "better", that kind of thinking is inapplicable)

- If you're using the MDC library already, or if you need some of `Slider`'s advanced capabilities, use Slider.
- If you only need a simple line with a circle sliding between two extremes, use `SeekBar` instead of pulling the MDC library just for that.